# Generating 6 digit number

Tags: c#

I am retrieving a number of records from a database, which I append to some string - for example:

```
spouse counter=1;
counter=1+counter;
```

then I get `customerID` in the following way:

```
customerID = "AGP-00000" + counter;
```

so that `customerID` will be `AGP-000001`.

For counter value `2` - the `customerID` string will be `AGP-000002`.

My problem is that, if counter is `10` then `customer ID` will be  `AGP-0000010`, and I want it to be `AGP-000010`.

How can I ensure that `customer ID` is always  like `AGP-000010`?

Comment: This is a terrible formated question.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül it is a pretty bad edited question as well.. You could have fixed "wil" > "will", "i" > "I", removed the C# tag in the title, added code formatting to "customerID" and on "AGP-000001".... Just saying.

Comment: @Default, usually the first edit would involve usage of code blocks *(if not done earlier)* , so that the question is more readable to the answerers. I think Soner has been doing a fine job with respect to editing, and we should appreciate it.

Comment: @Habib he fixed it, so I'm happy :) In my opinion, all errors should try to be fixed as soon as possible in one edit instead of letting several editors try to fix all of the issues. I'm sorry if it sounded condescending - I do appreciate his editing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int  number = 1;
string customerID = "AGP-" + number.ToString("D6");
```

customerID will be: `"AGP-000001"`

See: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Comment: it should be like int  number = 1;
string customerID = "AGP-" + number.ToString("D6"); number++;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it works

```
string str = "AGP-00000";
int counter = 100;
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - counter.ToString().Length + 1);
str += counter.ToString();
```